# How to show/hide label with if and else

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement

I'm a student and I'm experimenting with c# (I'm noob)
My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "test")
        {
            label1.Show();
            label2.Hide();
        }
        else
            label1.Hide();
        label2.Show();
    }
```

My problem is this:
I have two labels, one button and one textbox.

When the TextBox equals "test" if I click on it, I want to show `label1` and hide `label2`.

If the TextBox doesn't contain "test" I want to hide `label1` and show `label2`.

Now when I press the button without the text "test":
`label2` shows and `label1` is hidden

But if the text is "test" `label1` shows and `label2` still shows, why?

Comment: Wrap the last two statements with braces `{` and `}`. At the moment, it is always executing `label2.show()`

Comment: there is no `label2` in that code

Comment: One-liner `label2.Visible = !(label1.Visible = textBox1.Text == "test");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot braces in the else statement:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "test")
        {
            label1.Show();
            label2.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Hide();
            label2.Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

As stated by JayV you are missing curly brackets. The reason that `label1` will still show though (if you have the text "test") is because without brackets the next statement will (and only will) be executed as part of the `Else` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) and anything after that immediate next statement is not part of the if-else i.e. what you have written is:

- If the text in `textbox1` is "test" then show `label1`, hide `label2`.
- If the text in `textbox1` is not "test" then hide `label1`.
- Regardless of what the text is the code will run the final `label2.show`.

Effectively you've written

```
    if (textBox1.Text == "test")
    {
        label1.Show();
        label2.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Hide();
    }

    label2.Show();
```

When you want:

```
    if (textBox1.Text == "test")
    {
        label1.Show();
        label2.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Hide();
        label2.Show();
    }
```

I highly recommend you look at debugging, as stepping through your code would quickly show you this (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2017)